# llvm obfuscator passes doesnt work with opt

Tags: optimization, clang, llvm, obfuscation

im trying to use the llvm optimizer to load the obfuscation passes.
after i have an LLVM IR file like main.ll
i invoke this command :

```
opt -S -bcf -fla -sub main.ll -o main.ll.obf
```

i dont get any error after the invokation, but when i compare the input and output, i see no change.
what am i missing?

By the way, i'm aware of the -mllvm flag of the clang compiler but i need to compile with one compiler (which doesn't support -mllvm -fla etc..)
and then obfuscate with the optimizer.

I'll be glad for a help!

Comment: Maybe the reason is that there are no obfuscation passes in LLVM?

Comment: The official LLVM clang has no obfuscation in it. But i'm talking about Obfuscator-LLVM Project : https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki the optimizer there is already loaded with obfuscation passes and it can be seen when invoking `opt -help`